# Windows 8 weird sound distortion on recordings

Tags: windows, windows-8

When listening to any sound source like Youtube or BBC iPlayer the quality on this Windows 8 machine is ok. If I record the music on either Audacity or Windows sound recorder the playback sounds weird like the speakers were under water. Tried changing levels but no difference made. Any suggestions, folks?

Comment: Have you checked your mic??

Comment: No mic connected.

Comment: Ok after much fiddling can now load files of music and edit and resave them with no obvious distortion. However distortion very obvious when playing back after recording streaming audio. Not too much of a problem except where you cannot download files as in BBC iPlayer radio. I notice that when recording streaming audio the slider at the top right hand side of the Audacity control panel with the loudspeaker symbol controls recording level which strikes me as being odd. The other slider with the microphone symbol does nothing but then I don't have a mic connected to this machine............JR

Comment: Windows says drivers are up to date and only stero mix is enabled......JR

Comment: As an experiment I have downloaded a trial copy of Wondershare streaming audio recorder. This does not produce the distortion that I am hearing with Windows recorder or Audacity. So I can download music with Wondershare and then transfer the file and edit with Audacity but it is strange that Wondershare works ok in Windows 8 and Audacity and Windows own recorder has this problem. It has been suggested in another place that Beats Audio might be to blame.......JR